# (iTunes Connect) - Submit first app product

Tags: upload, in-app-purchase, itunes

I know that this question may have been asked several times, sorry, but I really can't find out how can I submit my first app product to the iTunes Connect. The In App Purchase section keep saying something like "Your first in app purchase must be send with a new app version", but my app is still in development and so it would be rejected.

Where do I have to upload it for approval?

Answer (score 0):

You have to finish your app first and have a working version ready.  In XCode simply click on your `device` selection where it usually says `iPhone 6` and select `iOS Device` on top.  Then Click on Product --> Archive.

Once the app is archived you can see on the right hand side a widget for submitting it to the appstore.

Make sure your provisioning profile is created, downloaded and installed from your [Developer Account](https://developer.apple.com).